# How to achieve Service timeout as Traffic Management Property in FastAPI?

Tags: python, timeout, fastapi

I have API built with FastAPI

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Optional

import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

class User(BaseModel):
    username: str

user_list = ["John", "Abrahim", "Kiana"]

#Get method to fetch some value
@app.get('/user/{id}/')
def users(id:int):
    return user_list[id]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1",port=8000)
```

How I can achieve Service Timeout for this API? Will be thankful for the suggestions and written example if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "Service Timeout"? What you've shared is just a very basic FastAPI app.

Comment: @M.O. Yeah so the api should timeout after certain seconds. Basically I want the api should return timeout error if it takes much time to send the response.

Comment: @Chris it actually helped me. I was bit confused with the code in get method but later on realized that, it wasn’t required for my case. Thanks for helping.